# Map dentro de componente no retorna los datos

Tags: reactjs

Estoy pasando un array mediante el prop data, y los datos vienen OK, pero cuando intento renderizarlos como una lista en una tabla, no me envía datos en console.log ni el JSX. El código que recibe este componente es un Table con un tbody, por lo tanto inserto el return en un fragment.

```
export default function TableEntries({ data }) {
  return (
    <>
      {data.map((doc) => {
        return (
          <tr key={doc.id}>
            <td>{doc.date}</td>
            <td>{doc.type === "exp" ? "Gasto" : "Ingreso"}</td>
            <td>{doc.title}</td>
            <td>{doc.categoryName}</td>
            <td>{doc.value}</td>
          </tr>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

Además aclaro que la información la traigo desde Firebase de la siguiente forma en un custom hook:

```javascript
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { DB } from "../api/config";
import AuthContext from "../context/AuthContext";

export function useEntriesList() {
  const [entries, setEntries] = useState([]);
  const user = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    DB.collection("registros")
      .where("userId", "==", user.uid)
      .onSnapshot((query) => {
        const docs = [];
        query.forEach((doc) => {
          let item = doc.data();
          item.id = doc.id;
          item.category.onSnapshot((doc) => {
            item.categoryName = doc.data().name;
          });
          docs.push(item);
        });
        setEntries(docs);
      });
  }, []);

  return entries;
}
```

retorno un array de objetos que en el `console.log` se visualizan los objetos.

UPDATE:
Logre solucionar que renderice los datos, al parecer era un error en el push dentro del custom hook. Pero no renderiza el field `categoryName` que es un docRef dentro de la colección. Lo muestra correctamente en los datos, pero no lo renderiza (lo muestra como undefined).

SOLUCION:
El push de la consulta final se realiza luego de ejecutar la segunda consulta en las categorias. Así logra traer resultados en el array. Persiste la novedad, ya que los datos son asincronos desde firebase y se debe esperar para poder renderizar los datos.

Gracias.